# How to determine whether third party library makes call to Apple's first party API?

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I currently have a third party Mach-O binary file that is part of a "Cocoa Touch framework." I am wondering if there is a way to determine from the code whether specific functions from Apple's first party API (for example CLLocationManager() from Core Location) are called by the third party binary. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your third party binary static or a dylib? If the library is not doing some crazy shenanigans to hide private api calls , you can inspect it with `Hopper` and search for anything suspicious. If it's static and pure obj-c you could do some runtime tracking. If you're interested in this topic let me know.

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. I am looking into it.